# scalable circels connected by line

Tags: css, transform

i want to make circles connected by a line in CSS. I have achieved that thanks to an answer here at Stackoverflow. But I want to scale the circles to twice their size on hover. But when I am doing so, the line before the circle is also getting scaled.

Given below is my styling

```css
li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li:hover {
  transform: scale(3);
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.active~li {
  background: lightblue;
}

.active~li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) on an element (here `li`), the dynamically added content will become the first *child* of that element. Hence, when you apply a scale to your `li`s, the scaling will also apply to the line added with `::before`.

**Solution:** Wrap the numbers in another element, for example a `span`, then scale the `span` instead of the `li`. This way, the line will not be affected anymore.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

li span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: white;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

li span:hover {
  transform: scale(3);
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  <li><span>7</span></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to use additional markup, you could also make use of `li:hover::before` in addition to `li::before` in order to create a properly sized and positioned line for the hovered circles. However, I would recommend against the use of `transform` in that case and instead just overwrite the `li`s `width`,  `height` and `border-radius` properties instead.